# Is there any widget app that will display stocks on Lubuntu 17.04?

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04, lxde, widgets

I would like an application that displays the current stock prices on the side of my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Desktop Ticker in Wine. It worked, but the ticker was in the middle of the screen. It wouldn't drag anywhere. I didn't try to move it any other way. I was able to start and stop it. I killed it from HTOP.

If you have a favorite that works in Windows, it will probably work in Wine.

Comment: Well yeah, but wine seems to really eat up my ram. Itd be nice to click my sidebar, type in my stock symbol then see its current state.  I'd be suprised if linux hasnt even thought of implimenting that.